# Save file name as first line in word and then increment

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-automation

I have this VBA macro script which I use in MS Word 2013 and it works well. However I need to change one part as it is causing some issues. (Full VBA script located below).

**Code Change**

```
baseFile.SaveAs _
            FileName:=saveFN & Format(iterNum, "0000") & ".prtl", _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatText, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False

        ' close the modified file without saving
        baseFile.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

        iterNum = iterNum + 1
    Next para
```

**Objective**

Instead of incrementing the file name, I would like it to take the first line of the text from the word doc and and use it as the file name and then the next word doc line for the next file name save.

**Example:**

**Word Doc Text:**

Perter Pan: /Green Pants/
Captain Hook: /Hook/

**Desired Results**

Perter Pan - Green Pants 
Captain Hook - Hook

**Notes:**

Please note that the "/" and must be removed and that the ":" should be replaced with "-" or the file cannot be saved.

**Full VBA Script:**

This script allows you to make titles for Adobe Premiere. If you need to make a lot of titles, this is the script for you.

```
Option Explicit

Sub EditVideoFile()
    Dim dataFile As Document    ' this data doc or template
    Dim baseFile As Document    ' file being modified
    Dim baseFileFN As String    ' path\name of file from Adobe
    Dim rgData As Range         ' range of data file containing replacements
    Dim para As Paragraph       ' paragraph in rgData
    Dim rgPattern As Range      ' a range used in baseFile
    Dim replaceText As String   ' current line from this data file
    Dim iterNum As Long         ' number of current line / saved file
    Dim saveFN As String        ' path\base name of saved file

    Set dataFile = ActiveDocument

    MsgBox "Select the data file (*.prtl) to be processed."
    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
        .Name = "*.prtl"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            Set baseFile = ActiveDocument   ' file just opened becomes Active
            baseFileFN = baseFile.FullName  ' this path\name will be used to open it again
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    MsgBox "Select the folder and filename (without numbers) to save as."
    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
        If .Display = -1 Then   ' just get the path\name, don't actually save
            saveFN = WordBasic.FileNameInfo(.Name, 5) & WordBasic.FileNameInfo(.Name, 4) & "-"
            'MsgBox saveFN
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    On Error GoTo Errhdl
    iterNum = 1
    Set rgData = dataFile.Range
    rgData.MoveStart unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1 ' exclude paragraph containing macro button
    For Each para In rgData.Paragraphs
        replaceText = Left(para.Range.Text, Len(para.Range.Text) - 1) ' exclude paragraph mark

        ' force all-caps XYZ to lower-case xyz
        ' to avoid inserting text from data file in all caps
        Set rgPattern = baseFile.Range
        With rgPattern.Find
            .Text = "XYZ"
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            While .Execute
                rgPattern.Text = LCase(rgPattern.Text)
            Wend
        End With

        ' do the replacement
        baseFile.Range.Find.Execute _
            FindText:="xyz", _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            ReplaceWith:=replaceText, _
            Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        baseFile.SaveAs _
            **FileName:=saveFN & Format(iterNum, "0000") & ".prtl", _**
            FileFormat:=wdFormatText, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False

        ' close the modified file, then reopen the unmodified base
        baseFile.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        Set baseFile = Documents.Open(FileName:=baseFileFN, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)

        iterNum = iterNum + 1
    Next para

    baseFile.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    MsgBox "Done"
    Exit Sub

Errhdl:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " at line " & iterNum & vbCr & Err.Description
End Sub
```

**Update**

I have changed

```
FileName:=saveFN & Format(iterNum, "0000") & ".prtl", _
```

to

```
FileName:=Format(replaceText) & ".prtl", _
```

and it give me the results I need however I need to figure out how to remove the "/" and ":".

Comment: consider using `Words collection` which could go in this way: `Activedocument.Words(1) & " " & Activedocument.words(2)`. Because `slashes` are part of `Words collection` then you need to check and omit them with simple `if statement`.

Comment: @KazJaw, ok, thank you. But I am still a little puzzled. I have a `Set rgData = dataFile.Range` Which has a lost all the lines of the word doc. Can I use this range to use a line at a time to use as the save file name.

Comment: Seems like an awful lot of text and code to ask *How do I remove '/' and ':' from a string?*

Comment: @KenWhite Suggest you read all of it, I have created a functional part and now I am left this little part to fix. I fixed part of the problem by doing some research.

Comment: So you asked one question and then figured it out, so you've changed the question but left all the text in from the first? It's no longer necessary if you've changed the question. (Which you should not do, BTW - you should be asking a new question if you now have a different one.) If you've solved the problem that the majority of the text and code addresses, and you now have a much diffferent question remaining, you edit to remove the unnecessary noise so your actual question is clear. (And I *did* in fact read it all, which is how I determined that most of it was unnecessary now.)

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry, no. It is the same problem. However there were 2 parts to it. I have solved 1 part, not the other. It is still part of the same question! Removing all the code does not help future people that may have the same issue.

Comment: If you had two questions in the first place, you should have posted two questions to start with, in separate posts. Now that you've solved one, what you're asking is totally different, and it's hard to pick out what you're actually asking now through the noise. It's OK, though; if you don't want to edit it to either a) move your current question out into a new post (you can link to this one for additional info) or b) edit this one to remove all of the no longer relevant text, then I can simply vote to close it as unclear. I'll leave the choices up to you.

Comment: I don't exacly understand what do you mean, in which way you are going decide where starts and ends the name of the file, how to refer it to line. Possilbly what you need is `Paragraph object`. Try with this `rgData.Paragraphs(1)` to get first paragraph (which could equal to your first line).